# Stripe checkOut method Content Security Policy Error

Tags: angular, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I added the stripe payment system to my application. I'm trying in test environment. Stripe's checkout ui is presented to the user when the user presses the button. There is no problem, everything works, even I can get payment from the user. Status succes. But I'm getting a lot of content security policy errors. I don't know if I will have problems in the future, and seeing these errors bothered me. I tried several methods but it didn't work. how can i solve these problems?

https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#content-security-policy

firebase Function :

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_51....');
const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:4200';
exports.test = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  return new Promise(async (Resolve, Reject) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: [
      {
        // Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
        price: 'price_1Mgx1cA',
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel.html`,
  });
Resolve(session.id)
  })
})
```

onSubmit() :

```
let x =  this.fnc.httpsCallable("test")({});
  x.subscribe(result=>{
    stripe?.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId : result,
    })
  })
```

index.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TestApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Those are report only CBSP errors, if your page is otherwise working you can ignore them for now. Stripe.js sometimes throws report only errors like this but Stripe makes sure to try to fix them as quickly as possible so as to not pollute your developer console.

Comment: @Pompey thank you for your answer. Are you dev in stripe ?